# No such file or directory - Python

Tags: python

**ANSWERED! THANKS EVERYONE!**

I'm trying to get my script to run, however I'm getting this error. I'm not brilliant with Python, so any form of basic explanation would be appreciated.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Brad>c:\python27\python.exe c:\python27\vsauce.py
ERROR:root:Error opening settings.json.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\vsauce.py", line 76, in loadSettings
    settingsFile = open("settings.json", "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'settings.json'
```

The line in question

```
        settingsFile = open("settings.json", "r")
```

Yes, the file exists. Yes, it is named "settings.json" exactly. I can't for the life of me figure out what the hell I have done wrong. This is not my script by the way.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In which directory does `settings.json` exist?

Comment: (Also, you wouldn't normally put your python scripts in `c:\python27`.)

Comment: The exact same directory, c:\python27

Comment: so just to be clear `C:\Users\Brad\settings.json` does exist?  since you are running your script from `C:\Users\Brad` that is where its looking ... this has nothing to do with python... it has to do with current working directory...

Comment: So changing my working directory to C:\python27 should fix that problem?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$ cd C:\Python27
$ python.exe vsauce.py
```

this will move you to Python27 directory. so it will look there for settings.json

since you ran it from `C:\Users\Brad` it was looking for `C:\Users\Brad\settings.json`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your script isn't working is because you're running it from `C:\Users\Brad`, so when

```
settingsFile = open("settings.json", "r")
```

runs, it looks for `settings.json` in the directory the script *was run from*, not the directory the script is stored in. You either need to hardcode the path the `settings.json` in your `.py` file, or you need to run the script from the `C:\Python27` directory. To do this, after starting `cmd.exe`, enter

```
cd c:\Python27
python vsauce.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Try opening while writing out the full directory. It may be that your current working directory is not the same as where the file is. By default when you use "open" python looks for files wherever you ran the program from. Such as 'C:\Users\Brad... whatever'. You need to change the directory if the file is saved elsewhere

```
settingsFile = open('C:\\Users\\Brad\\Documents\\PythonFiles\\YourDirectory\\settings.json', 'r')
```

Comment: no, by default Python looks for files in the directory you run the script from, not where Python is installed.